# How to get original indexpath in filtered uitableview swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a **uitableView** that need to search on it. When I click on a cell it shows an indicator in that cell(it is multi selection table). Every thing works very well up to here. However, when I search something and back to original table the returned index is not the original index and it indicates a wrong cell. I see a lot of question in stackoverflow but they use **storyboards** or they are in **Objective-c** that I don't understand.

**How can I get original indexPath in searched table?**

In **ContactListView**:

```
extension ContactListView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (presenter?.isSelectionMode)! {
            self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdContactSelection, for: indexPath) as! ContactListCellSelection
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                cell.dataSourceItem = filteredItems[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                cell.dataSourceItem = presenter?.items?[indexPath.item]
            }
            return cell
        }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (presenter?.isSelectionMode)! {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ContactListCellSelection
            // configure decides to show indicator or not
            configure(cell!, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            return filteredItems.count
        }
        let count = presenter?.items?.count ?? 0
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
        if count == 0 {
            tableView.EmptyMessage(title: NSLocalizedString("no_transaction_contact", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("no_transaction_press_plus_button_contact", comment: ""))
        }
        return count
    }
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        filteredItems = (presenter?.items?.filter { item in
            return item.displayName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            })! 
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
extension ContactListView: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the ``rowIsSelected``` flag to your in memory data source

Comment: @Wainage it is not working.

Comment: I has to. When a row is selected, you add "isSelected" to your data in your collection. Even if you filter that collection the row's data source will have the "isSelected" variable. On table re-render you check for that flag. Couldn't be simpler

Comment: In **didSelectRowAt** I use configure that need original indexPath. In that method indexPath uses for some logic. So I need indexPath there.

Comment: No you don't. ```indexPath``` is only a pointer to your current table state. Use that to insert ```isSelected``` into your data source. You data source is ALWAYS the source of truth

Answer (score 1):

For the future viewers, this is what you need to do:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var selectedObject = searchedArray[indexPath.row]
    var index = OrignalArray.index(of: selectedObject)
    print("index:", index) // This will give you index of selected array from the original array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you select one  cell and  then select another cell.And  u want to save which cell is the last  selected cell?
If  so, you can use lastSelectedIndexPath(maybe something else you want to name)to mark the last selected cell.